# Stop jquery UI resize from forcing elements to be absolutely positioned

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a very simple script that utilises the jquery library and allows me to drag and resize the element with the class "moveabledraggable".

```
$(".moveabledraggable").draggable({
   stop: function(){
     alert('dragging stopped');
}
}).resizable({
   stop: function(){
     alert('resizing stopped');
}
});
```

It works perfectly, except I want "moveabledraggable" to be fixed on the screen as a user scrolls. It needs to be positioned using "fixed". Dragging the element doesn't alter my hardcoded inline style

```
position: fixed;
```

but on resizing the element, jquery ui changes it to

```
position: relative;
```

How can I stop this? Don't know if it's possible, but dragging and positioning (which is harder) doesn't change the position from fixed, so maybe it can be done.

[Jsfiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/BG9r2/2/)

(Jsfiddle doesn't actually work (possibly due to how it uses sub-windows within the viewport), but it can be copy-pasted to a jquery-ui linked local file.)

Comment: Whenever I try it I always get `position: relative`.

Comment: maybe you can set the parent of the elements to position: fixed instead? the children should then have a fixed position allthough they themselves are positioned relative, shouldnt they?

Comment: @jascha That's good! I'll implement tomorrow

Comment: Actually...I'm not sure if that'll work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh don't know why I didn't think of this at first. Just re-append inline css like this:

```
$(".moveabledraggable").draggable({
   stop: function(){
     alert('dragging stopped');
}
}).resizable({
   stop: function(){
     alert('resizing stopped');
     $(".moveabledraggable").css("position", "fixed");     
}
});
```

Comment: Haven't accepted this as an answer mind. Open to less hacky solutuions!

Comment: The solution of setting the `position` to `fixed` worked for me **but** without using the `stop` function. I set that property directly into the `style` of my `div`.